# Vim workflow - debugging and bringing up Terminal

Tags: vim, macvim

I just made the switch to vim from emacs, using MacVim with Janus.
In emacs, you can have a buffer solely for shell use. Is this possible in MacVim? It would be very helpful when debugging.

Which also brings me to ask - is there a way to compile in vim similar to emacs: where you type meta-x compile, and then are able to click on errors to bring the cursor to the relevant line?

I'm just trying to figure out a good workflow for MacVim, and want a good way to fix my bugs without having to line up Terminal and MacVim side by side. Any recommendations appreciated.

Comment: What language are you compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile with `:make`, if you have a makefile. Vim can parse the output of GCC and jump to the errors with `:cnext` and `:cprevious`. I don’t think vim knows how to parse the output of gfortran, and I haven’t used it with any other compilers.

I don't know of any way to keep a shell open in a buffer.

Comment: You can actually use this even without Makefiles.  Just lookup the documentation for 'makeprg' and 'efm' to see how to use different compilers / build systems with different error format messages.  Having different settings for those based on filetype are extremely useful.

Answer (score 5):

*Vim* does not do any terminal emulation itself, but you can use the [Conque plugin](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) to provide terminal emulation inside a *Vim* window. Conque requires a Python-enabled *Vim* (*MacVim* is sufficient).

However, if you workflow is focused on just jumping to locations reported by command-line tools, then you really should try using the quickfix system (see [`:help quickfix`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html)).

Typically, you just run [`:make`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake) to invoke your compiler (usually via `make`, but customizable with [the `makeprg` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake); also see [`:compiler`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler)), and *Vim* will use the value of [the `errorformat` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27errorformat%27) to [parse](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#errorformat) any resulting messages and build a quickfix list. You can then navigate the reported locations with commands like

- [`:cc N`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acc) — goto location number N,
- [`:cn`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acn) — next location,
- [`:cp`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acp) — previous location,
- [`:cnf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acnf) — next location in next file (i.e. skip the rest of the locations in the current file),
- [`:cw`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acw) — open the location list in a buffer where you can see the messages and press Enter to jump to the location.

The default value of `makeprg` and `errorformat` is usually fine for parsing the output of `make` and `cc`/`gcc`, but it may need changes to handle the messages from other build systems or compilers.

The [`:grep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Agrep) command works similarly to `:make` (it populates the quickfix list with locations reported by a `grep` command).

Comment: I think you mean "Vim *doesn't* do any terminal emulation itself"?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the compiler output goes to the quickfix or location buffers, then yes, you can easily jump from errors to their locations in the source code.  Vim has a reasonable set of defaults for parsing Make and GCC; other formats can be added with [`:set efm`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Errorformats).

Running an interactive shell inside Vim doesn't work out of the box, but there are plugins like [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/) which provide it.